# php require_once not working the way I want it to.. relative path issue

Tags: php, require-once

I'm having problems assigning a relative path to require_once. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm not seeing...

folder directory structure
level 1: site
level 2: include
level 2: class

so...
site/include/global.php <-- this is where function autoload is being called from
site/class/db.php

when I attempt to use

```
function__autoload($className)
{
     require_once '../class/'.$className.'.php';

}
```

i get:

Warning: require_once(../class/db.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../class/db.php' (include_path='.;./includes;./pear')

What am I doing wrong? It'll work fine if I plop the global.php in the class folder so I'm assuming it's my poor understanding of relative paths that is causing the problem..

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`require(_once)` and `include(_once)` work relative to the path of the **first** script, i.e. **the script that was actually called**.

If you need to `require` something in an included or required file, and would like to work relative to that file, use

```
dirname(__FILE__)."/path/to/file";
```

or as @Arkh points out, from PHP 5.3 upwards

```
__DIR__."/path/to/file";
```

Comment: Too fast:(. You can also use `__DIR__` with php5.3+

Comment: thanks mate.

require_once  dirname(__FILE__).'/../class/'.$className .'.php';

works perfectly!

I didn't know that require starts at the root directory by default. I assumed (you should never assume) that it was from current directory.

Anyways, Thanks Pekka.

Comment: @payling You're welcome. One important distinction, by "root" I mean the script that was called in the browser, not necessarily the root directory. My choice of words was a bit misleading, sorry. I've edited it a bit.

Comment: Gotcha. the home page (that calls autoload function) is located in site directory. 
The global.php page is in my include directory but since I included the global.php inside home page it's techinically in the site directory for the moment. 'class/'.$className.'.php'; works, but it's probably best to use the first solution we came up with using the dirname because I could be including script form a location other than the site directory so 'class/' will not always work! Thanks again!

Comment: Exactly. Perfectly put! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work (apache only, i *believe*)

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/class/' . $classname '.php');
```

Comment: I don't want to use document root because I'm working off the site remotely. I have two versions of the site, the main site and my test version and the site folder is named differently from the test version. Absolute paths will not work if I want to have both the test and main working correctly.. : /

Comment: Oh.  Not separate ports, just /test and /main.  That means that your dev env isn't a mirror of how you will deploy, but I know the temptation.