# How to require_once in a function that is used in different directories

Tags: php, function

I need to require a file inside of a function like so:

```
function MyFunction(){
    require_once('../../myfile.php');
    //do stuff
}
```

This function may be used anywhere on the site so the path for the required file should not change. I tried using `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));` but that changes the directory of my other files later on in the php, which is not desired.

When I am in various directories throughout the website I get an error message that the required file failed to open stream.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to use `require_once(__DIR__'/../myfile.php')` this question provided a similar solution:

[php require_once not working the way I want it to.. relative path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253625/php-require-once-not-working-the-way-i-want-it-to-relative-path-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for things like this.   It relies on where your document root is set up in your virtual host file though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute paths in this case.

In your `index.php` you should get the location of your index.php file, that will be your reference point:

```
<?php

// store it in a constant, this info will not be changed anyway
define('APP_PATH',dirname(__FILE__));

//... rest of your code here
```

And, when you have to do a require_once for that file (let's say `myfile.php` is 2 directories above your `index.php` file):

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(APP_PATH)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myfile.php');
```

or if `myfile.php` is in the same directory with index.php:

```
require_once(APP_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myfile.php');
```

**Note**

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is the PHP constant for the path delimiter (`/` in any Linux, Unix, Mac, etc, or `\` in Windows.